# What is a gmail addon's lifecycle ? Do we have lifecycle hooks for addons?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Currently I understand that a gmail add-on loads only when we open a message. Reopening the message does not reload the add-on, this means that the addon might show outdated info. Which in my case , it does. Hence I would like to fully understand it lifecycle. And do some operation in case if it supports some lifecycle hooks.

Comment: You can absolutely flag your addon to require it be built every time, i.e. that its `state` has changed due to an action

Comment: Can you share the link to the documentation about state? I will try your suggestion.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action-response-builder#setstatechangedstatechanged see also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80269537